# Given a UTC date, how do you correctly set value for Adaptive Card - Date Picker?

Tags: datepicker, microsoft-teams, date-formatting, adaptive-cards

Here is the card template:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "title": "Given Date 1",
                    "value": "${string(dueDate)}"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Formatted Date 1",
                    "value": "{{DATE(${string(dueDate)}, COMPACT)}}"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Given Date 2",
                    "value": "${dueDateTicks}"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Formatted Date 2",
                    "value": "${formatTicks(int(dueDateTicks), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Date",
            "id": "date",
            "value": "${formatDateTime(dueDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2"
}
```

And here's the sample given data:

```
{
    "dueDate": "2020-11-30T21:00:00Z",
    "dueDateTicks": "637423668000000000"
}
```

When you try this on the designer preview, it renders correctly (local @ GMT+8): 2020-12-01

```
Given Date 1
2020-11-30T21:00:00Z
Formatted Date 1
12/1/2020

Given Date 2
637423668000000000
Formatted Date 2
2020-12-01

DatePicker Value
12/01/2020
```

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkgS7.png)

But on teams, the Date Picker and formatted date values are off (local @ GMT+8): 2020-11-30

```
Given Date 1
11/30/2020 21:00:00
Formatted Date 1
12/1/2020

Given Date 2
637423668000000000
Formatted Date 2
2020-11-30

DatePicker Value
30 Nov 2020
```

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjxSB.png)

Comment: Please update your title so that it summarizes your question. Moreover, even the content of your question does not include a specific question!

Comment: Title has been updated to include the question. The main problem is that the Date Picker and formatted date values are off in user timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activity class has a "LocalTimestamp" field that you should use to instantiate the date according the user's locale. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activity.localtimestamp?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Schema_Activity_LocalTimestamp) for more info. Dealing with this is obviously platform specific (you haven't said what platform you're on), but for C#, for instance, you can deal with this via the [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.

Just wondering if there's other prebuilt function for this in adaptivecards, instead of preformatting the data on backend. Or a possibility for the Date formatting to be custom other than just COMPACT, SHORT and LONG. Would be really helpful on cases where you won't know the timezone of the user receiving the card, that is sending cards as notifications, so there's no Activity context beforehand.

Comment: I was able to identifiy the timezone from the LocalTimestamp in the bot Activity context. Then used convertFromUTC method in the AdaptiveCard template.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#convertFromUTC